# ImportError when importing TensorFlow in PyCharm with Python 3.11 due to missing 'msvcp140_1.dll'

Tags: tensorflow, visual-c++, pycharm, windows-10, tensorflow2.0

**Context:** I am currently working on setting up PyCharm and TensorFlow to prepare for the TensorFlow Professional Developer Certificate.

Objective: My goal is to create a suitable environment that allows me to effectively practice and prepare for the TensorFlow Professional Developer Certificate.

**The problem:**

I recently installed the latest version of PyCharm (2023.1.2) with Python 3.11 as the interpreter. In PyCharm's console, I installed TensorFlow using 'pip install tensorflow'. However, upon trying to import TensorFlow, I encountered the following error message:

"ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory listed in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading the "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019" for your platform from this URL: [https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads"](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads%22)

**Attempts Made:**

I attempted to resolve the issue by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package (VC_redist.x86) and reboot, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

I also tried to download the **'msvcp140_1.dll'** and **'msvcp140.dll'** manually and copy paste them in Python 311 directory but the problem also persists.

Could someone please help me resolve this **'msvcp140_1.dll'** ImportError issue with TensorFlow in PyCharm?

Any guidance or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Note:

- OS: Windows 10

- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6198DU CPU @ 2.30GHz   2.40 GHz

- PyCharm Version: 2023.1.2

- Python Interpreter: 3.11

- TensorFlow Version: 2.13 (latest version) (CPU only)

- VC++ Redistributable Version: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe (latest supported version)